# I can access my site via ports 8443 and 8080 but not via 443 and 80 (Tomcat)

Tags: windows-server-2008, ssl, tomcat, port, redirection

I am using Tomcat7 on Windows Server 2008

My Server.xml is set up as follows:

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000"
redirectPort="443"
compression="on"   compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,
text/plain,text/javascript,
text/jsp,text/css"/

<Connector port="443" maxThreads="200" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
keystoreFile="C:\program files\java\jre7\bin\tomcat.keystore"
keystorePass="password" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>

<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="443" />
```

However when I go to http://www.example.com or https://www.example.com then no page is displayed.

If I do a search and replace, changing port "80" for "8080" and port "443" for "8443" then my website works perfectly, although I need to access it via http://www.example.com:8080 and https://www.example.com:8443

I would like access to the site to be without having to specify the port numbers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is very simple!
The ports 80 and 443 were blocked on the Firewall.
I unblocked them by using the following [deprecated] commands from the command line:

```
netsh firewall set portopening tcp 80 smb enable 
netsh firewall set portopening tcp 443 smb enable
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you running IIS on the same machine? Could be that IIS is consuming TCP ports 80 and 443.
You can view all open TCP ports via CMD command: "netstat -at"

Comment: Comment to Sven: Thank you... IIS is not installed on the server, and nothing else seems to be using using ports 80 or 443. (after checking with netstat -at)

Comment: I neglected to mention that this machine is a cloud server.  Is it possible the cloud mechanism is getting in the way somehow?